# Why ASP.NET Core solution is falling after migrating to Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to migrate existing Web API solution to Visual Studio 2017.

It worked perfectly in Visual Studio 2015.

I followed automatic upgrade to VS 2017, but after starting solution with debugging it breaks and I get this error :

```
code:-32000
message:No script for id: 35
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.4\System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[6264] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).
The program '[14468] chrome.exe: WebKit' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[5056] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

After starting solution without debugging getting
[this error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j7PA.jpg).

It is not possible to debug solution at all. It breaks.

I can provide more informations, but right now don't know which are relevant.

EDIT:
The solution consist of 3 projects. project.json and .csproj files of each project, as well as launchSettings.json  are [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-V5-cc2b4PQdWpiOXYwRFB4UUE). They reflect state after my dependencies consolidation.

Also, I can share the whole solution, so you can try to migrate by yourself.

Comment: try running it without IIS (where you have the start debugging button, click the little arrow and choose the name of your project, it will start KESTREL instead of hosting it in IIS)

It's probably crashing because of a missing dependency

Comment: https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/migrating-project-json-to-csproj-visual-studio-2017

Comment: try to clear the local nuget cache

Comment: @DOMZE Result of that is dialog box "dotnet has stopped" working.
Checked all dependencies recently. Not sure did I that well.
How to be sure which dependencies are missing?

Comment: @SFin i've had a problem like this similar in the past where the versions of the dependency were not equal. I.E i had a 1.1.0 version and in another referencing project, I had 1.0.1. Missing and/or incompatible dependencies

Comment: @DOMZE Tried to stabilize dependencies already. Installed those I had on VS 2015 version of project.

Comment: @SFin if you try to load it in kestrel, do you see any exceptions? Like filenotfound exception?

Comment: @Alex How to clear local NuGet cache in VS 2017?

Comment: @DOMZE Getting just this error: `'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\1.0.4\System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[16352] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).`

Comment: navigate to %USERPROFILE%/.nuget and delete the contents

Comment: @Alex Done. Didn't helped.

Comment: Can you share the project.json file you had, and the new csproj file generated by the upgrade? Also, launchsettings.json?

Comment: @natemcmaster Just posted in edit. Thanks.

Comment: @DOMZE I found that one project is using dependency IdentityServer4 1.0.0-rc2 and another version 1.0.0-rc3. Updated latest one and than get `Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project AssetServer could not be loaded.` after reopening solution.

But, different versions of the same dependency has worked well in VS 2015 I think.

Comment: @Alex Your link to blog post helped me to find solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was bug in VS 2017 version 15.0 (26228.12). Upgraded to version 15.1 (26403.03) and error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

According @DOMZE result

> try running it without IIS (where you have the start debugging button, click the little arrow and choose the name of your project, it will start KESTREL instead of hosting it in IIS) It's probably crashing because of a missing dependency

Secondly fallowing the @Alexan link to try all steps [Migration from project.json to csproj](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/migrating-project-json-to-csproj-visual-studio-2017) . And doing the same thing what @Alexan mean that

> try to clear the local nuget cache

After I tried those and couldn't fix the error. And I tried to following link to install core 2.0 sdk. And restart the visual studio 2017.

Here is the Link [.net core 2.0 sdk](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd)

Note that if the link is gone you can find to google it to find ".net core 2.0 sdk".